# WebDAV drive map error 67 on Windows Server clients (not Win 7/10)

Tags: windows, iis, webdav

I have an IIS server that I've configured WebDAV on so a certain directory can be drive mapped on remote clients.  Almost of the client computers that will need to use this are Windows Servers versions from 2008 R2 through to 2016.

On my Windows 10 PC, I can drive map the WebDAV URL without issue.  I'm on the LAN.  I can also map it on my home PC fine - it is also Windows 10, but on an entirely different network.  Also connects OK on Windows 7 systems on the LAN and elsewhere on the internet.

The command I'm using is `net use p: http://pe-distribution.corporatedomain.com.au /User:pe.user P@ssw0rd /Persist:YES` and the P: drive appears straight away and I can read/write without issue.

[image]

But if I try to run the same on any of the client servers (Windows Server Std 2008 R2/2012/2012 R2/2016) that will need to use it, I receive the very unhelpful

> System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found.

I've even tested other Windows Servers on the same LAN as the ISS server and they fail.

Is there any security policy or registry settings in the Windows Server OS that need to be modified for NET USE to work with http/https?
Or something else I've missed in the IIS config?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't know if this is a proper solution or not, but it seems to have worked.

On each of the Windows Server 2008 R2, 2012 and 2012 R2 systems I installed the "Desktop Experience" feature and was able to map the drive.
For the Windows Server 2016 system - which was installed as "Desktop Experience" (as opposed to the core install) - I had to add the "WebDAV Redirector" feature.

So obviously Win 7/8.1/10 have the WebDAV redirector (WebClient) baked in, but the server OS needs the feature to be added.

I find it strange that it is required at all for a WebDAV client.

Anyhow, because of the inconsistencies with the Windows WebDAV client, I've added an extra step in my drive mapping batch file.  Some of the systems didn't map the drive on the first attempt, but did on the second.  So by using the authentication without mapping a drive letter, it initiates the connection so the drive map then worked without fail.

The batch file is scheduled to run each day at 6am and on system restart in order to keep the drive available.

```
@echo off
net use P: /DELETE /Y
net use pe-distribution.corporatedomain.com.au /User:pe.user P@ssw0rd /PERSIST:Yes
TIMEOUT /T 3
net use P: pe-distribution.corporatedomain.com.au /User:pe.user P@ssw0rd /PERSIST:Yes
```